# Symfony4 security login form

Tags: php, symfony, security, fosuserbundle

I have a problem with login form in Symfony4. I use FOSUserBundle for security on my site, but i can't log in. It's my code:

security.yaml

```
security:
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
encoders:
    App\Entity\User:
        algorithm: sha512
providers:
    user_provider:
        entity:
            class: App\Entity\User

firewalls:

    main:
        anonymous: ~
        provider: user_provider
        form_login:
            login_path: security_login
            check_path: security_login
```

login.html.twig

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% block body %}
{% if error %}
    <div class="error">{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 
'security') }}</div>
{% endif %}
{{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_row(form._username) }}
    {{ form_row(form._password) }}
    <button type="submit">Zaloguj</button>
{{ form_end(form) }}
{% endblock %}
```

and my controller

```
public function login(Request $r, AuthenticationUtils $authUtils) {
    $error = $authUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

    $lastUsername = $authUtils->getLastUsername();

    $form = $this->createForm(LoginType::class, [
        '_username' => $lastUsername
    ]);

    return $this->render('home/login.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'error' => $error
    ));
}
```

And when I try to log in, my console send me an error:

```
[info] Authentication request failed
[debug] Authentication failure, redirect triggered
```

Passwords and username is ok I think... Why I can't log in?

Comment: One problem is the generated names of you user/password input elements.  Do a ctrl-u in your browser to see the name and then add the correct names under your form_login section.  https://symfony.com/doc/master/reference/configuration/security.html#username-parameter  You may or may not have a csrf issue as well.

Comment: Why are you overwriting the controller? And yes, you forgot the token.https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_templates.html